# How do I display name instated of Id

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3

I have two table  Test1 and Test2.

**Test1**

```
p_id|imp_id | Name    |  Member_type  
1   |001    | A       |  1    
2   |002    | B       |  2     
3   |003    | C       |  1     
4   |004    | D       |  2
```

**Test2**

```
r_id|p_id |secondary_type  
1   |1    |2    
2   |3    |4
```

I am using join to get my design output.

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM `test1` JOIN `test2` ON `test2`.`secondary_type` = `test1`.`p_id`
```

My output is

```
p_id    imp_id  Name    Member_type     r_id    p_id    secondary_type  
2       002     B       2               1       1       2
4       004     D       2               2       3       4
```

So I am getting `p_id` value. I have to display name instated of the Id value.

For example `B` is connected to A. So I am getting the ID of A but I need Name instated of ID.

So my output will

```
p_id    imp_id  Name    Member_type     r_id |  p_id|   secondary_type  
2       002     B       2               1    |   A  |   2
4       004     D       2               2    |   C  |   4
```

I tried using CodeIgniter.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('test1');
$this->db->join('test2', 'test2.secondary_type = test1.p_id');
```

Comment: Just do: **`test1`.`name` as `p_id`**

Comment: Where I have to use this? in the query?

Comment: Based on your sample data, where are you getting the value `poikj` for `Name` ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, I added wrongly. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using alias in select statement like

```
SELECT 
test1.p_id,test1.imp_id,test2.name,test1.member_type,test2.r_id,test1.name as 
p_id,test2.secondary_type 
FROM `test1` JOIN `test2` 
ON `test2`.`secondary_type` = `test1`.`p_id`
```

Result will come as per your requirement.

Comment: Can you share the complete query? because I am not getting it.

Comment: I am getting the error  #1054 - Unknown column 'test2.name' in 'field list'

Comment: from where you take 'poikj' and 'asdffsdf' value ??? and how you created this tast1 & tast2 table....I think you need to update your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183707/discussion-between-user9437856-and-mukund).